# Threat Management Gateway (TMG) 2010 will not NAT

Tags: nat, microsoft-ftmg

I've got a TMG 2010 Standard server. Using the Web Proxy works **brilliantly**, however the server just does not seem to NAT any requests.

The clients all have the TMG box set as their default gateway (`192.168.161.1`) and the network rules are almost straight out of the box, so I can't see any reason why NAT wouldn't work:

[image: TMG 2010 will not NAT]

Any suggestions on how I can get NAT working via TMG?

Comment: Never used TMG, but do you have a packet filter rule to go along with your NAT setup?  What's the value of "Default IP Address"?  You could try plugging a hub and a laptop into the outside interface of TMG and run wireshark to see if anything's getting out (and possibly NATing as the wrong IP).

Comment: @Gravyface, at the exact time you were posting that message, I discovered you were 100% correct - there was a packet filter rule that was screwing it all up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out there was a "Fat Finger" rule that had accidentally denied HTTP, HTTPS and DNS access from a certain subnet. I found it after just plodding around investigating every single setting (it only took 3 hours).

So, lesson learned: If TMG will not NAT, it's probably a firewall rule that's blocking access from your subnet.